# How exactly does the Backbone.extend function work?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I would like to know how this `extend` function works in Backbone.js. And please help me with internally what exactly it is doing.

```
var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {
    var parent = this;
    var child;

    // The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
    // (the "constructor" property in your `extend` definition), or defaulted
    // by us to simply call the parent constructor.
    if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, "constructor")) {
      child = protoProps.constructor;
    } else {
      child = function() {
        return parent.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    }

    // Add static properties to the constructor function, if supplied.
    _.extend(child, parent, staticProps);

    // Set the prototype chain to inherit from `parent`, without calling
    // `parent`'s constructor function and add the prototype properties.
    child.prototype = _.create(parent.prototype, protoProps);
    child.prototype.constructor = child;

    // Set a convenience property in case the parent's prototype is needed
    // later.
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

    return child;
  };
```

here why the parent is added to child variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend` takes two params `protoProps` and `staticProps`. `protoProps` are properties that will be assigned to the Class prototype so that when you create an instance of the object the object will have that property as part of its prototype chain[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes). `staticProps` are props that are not available to objects created from the Class (using `new`), but are accessible from the class itself, for example, by calling `CatClass.defaultMeow`.

```
var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {
    var parent = this;
    var child;
```

In the discussion below `parent` is the what we will call the Base Class, the class which prototype we want to extend to the `child`, which here we will call the Extended Class.

```
    // The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
    // (the "constructor" property in your `extend` definition), or defaulted
    // by us to simply call the parent constructor.
    if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, "constructor")) {
      child = protoProps.constructor;
```

if `protoProps` is a function, or has a `constructor` property (this is the property that is invoked (as a method) whenever you call `new` on a Class).

```
    } else {
      child = function() {
        return parent.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    }
```

If not, the Extended Class will use the parent's `constructor` (when you call `new` it will invoke the parent's `constructor` method).

```
    // Add static properties to the constructor function, if supplied.
    _.extend(child, parent, staticProps);
```

`_.extend(target, src1,...,srcN)` an UnderscoreJS method does a shallow copy of the source objects' properties to the target object. Here were copying all of the parents (static) properties and all the properties pass in to the `staticProp` object (if supplied) to the new Extended Class.

```
    // Set the prototype chain to inherit from `parent`, without calling
    // `parent`'s constructor function and add the prototype properties.
    child.prototype = _.create(parent.prototype, protoProps);
```

This is probably the most important function of the Backbone.extend routine: this is where the Extended Class "inherits" the base Class' prototype chain. For example, if `AnimalClass.prototype.walk` is a method in the prototype chain for `AnimalClass`, `_.create(parent.prototype, protoProps)` will create a new Class with the the `walk` method in this new Class prototype chain, as well as all the `protoProps` passed in. This is, in essence, the _extended prototype chain` and it gets assigned to the Extended Class, as it's prototype.

```
 child.prototype.constructor = child;
```

This is line is confusing at first since we saw in conditional statement above that the Extended Class was already assigned a constructor. Well, it did, but in the last statement, when we did `_.create(...)` we overwrote the  Extended Class' constructor with the Base Class' constructor! Now we're reassigning it.

```
    // Set a convenience property in case the parent's prototype is needed
    // later.
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
```

Like the comment says, the Extended Class has access to the Base Class in the ***static property* `__super__`. It's a convenience property that is accessed from the Extended Class object itself. In our previous example, then, if a`CatClass` is extended from `AnimalClass`, then the following is true: `CatClass.__super__ === AnimalClass`.

```
    return child;
  };
```